# How to call function to display message on click of link

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, visibility

I have an requirement to display message like "processing" on click of link

Here's the scenario : My Page contains datas in that one of the data will be hyperlink  when the user click the link it is passed to controller, from controller calls DAO to fetch data from DB and then forwards to Page2. Page2 takes considerable time to load since it retrieves lot of its content from the DB.

How can I implement something where once the user click the hyper link on Page1, a "Please wait processing..." message and then as soon as Page2 is ready it forwards to Page2?

I need to display message when the user clicks  link.

Any body help an easy method .

My code is like below: Page 1 contains :

```
            <td class='tblData'><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servlet/VisibilityController?searchType=workSearchDetails&workNo=<%=installAtLocListBean.getWorkNumber()%>&ID=<%= firstLocationNumber %>&sitePosition=<%=pagePosition%>"><%=installAtLocListBean.getWorkNumber()%></a></td>
```

Not good in function.Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to hide elements and ajax to display results from another page

[Using AJAX and JSP](https://blog.udemy.com/jsp-ajax/)

EDIT:
I'm not familiarized with JSP but I can give you a example of how to show/hide elements with Jquery and Html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph. click the button to hide me </p>

<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[JQuery Toogle Usage](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)

In the same way you use toggle, you can use just the methods .hide and .show to **hide** the initial frame with a form for example and **show** a "Please wait processing..." Div, and when Ajax get the response from the data  from jsp you can hide the "please wait proccessing.." div and show the form with the data again.

Comment: Thanks I am not good in Ajax and script.Can you provide some examples please